# apt-get update error "Network is unreachable"

Tags: updates, repositories

sudo apt-get update command is:

Translated  into English (Google):

> Error: 7 http://en.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
>   tr.archive.ubuntu.com:80 link can not be started (2001: a98: 11 ::
>   100). -  connect (101: Network not available) [IP: 2001: a98: 11 ::
>   100 80] Error: 8 http://en.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates
>   InRelease tr.archive.ubuntu.com:80 link can not be started (2001: a98:
>   11 :: 100). - connect (101: Network not available) [IP: 2001: a98: 11
>   :: 100 80] Error: 9 
>   xenial-backports InRelease

Can you help?

Comment: have you tried running it a few times within a minute? also, please give more info about your network card and router settings. That way it is easier to recognize the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes the regional mirrors can have issues. Davin Miler is correct, have patience and try again, but alternatively, you can use another mirror (you are using tr.archive.ubuntu.com)

> Open your `sources.list` file using your favorite text editor, e.g.
>
> ```
> sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
> ```
>
> Locate the text `http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu` and replace it
>   with `http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu`.

The answer for doing this is here:

https://askubuntu.com/a/104701/649018